# angular 6 convert html to image

Tags: angular6

I want to convert my HTML element to png. So I'm using the `html-to-image` package to do this. I'm getting a blank image when I'm converting. Here is my code

```
<div #myDiv id="content" [innerHTML]="tempInnerHtml"></div>
<img [src]="snapshot">

this.tempInnerHtml = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(this.tempValue);
    var node = document.getElementById('content');
    htmlToImage.toPng(node)
      .then((dataUrl) => {
        console.log(dataUrl);
        this.snapshot = dataUrl;
  }).catch((error) => {
    console.error('oops, something went wrong!', error);
  });
```

My inner HTML loads without any problem but the output image is always a blank image. Can anyone help me to solve this? Thank you.